# How can I make an NSOutlineView where some of the entires are buttons?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I want to create an NSOutlineView subclass where some of the entries look like buttons. It would look something like this:

```
+ Fruits
  + Organic
    - Apples
    - Bananas
    [Add Item]
  + Non-organic
    - Cherries
    [Add Item]
  [Add Item]
+ Vegetables
  - Carrots
  [Add Item]
```

Where all of the "[Add Item]"'s are buttons.

I have a feeling this involves using the outlineView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:item: delegate method somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to implement the `outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:item:` method in your outline view's delegate to return an NSButtonCell for the rows where you want a button, and an NSTextFieldCell for the other rows.  Note that this delegate method was added in 10.5, if you need to support 10.4 or earlier, then you'll need to have a custom NSTableColumn subclass that overrides the `dataCellForRow:` method.